# How do I get the MsalGuard to use my client ID?

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am trying to set up my Angular app to use @azure/msal-angular. I have setup the MsalModule like so:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { MsalModule, MsalInterceptor } from "@azure/msal-angular";
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from "@angular/common/http";

console.log(`window populated: ${(window as any).APP_SETTINGS.aadAppClientId}`);
export const msalModuleForRoot = MsalModule.forRoot({
  clientID: (<any>window).APP_SETTINGS.aadAppClientId,
});

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    msalModuleForRoot,
  ],
  exports: [
    MsalModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
  ],
})
export class AppMsalModule { }
```

This module is imported in my app.module.browser.ts. The console log prints out my client ID successfully.

Then in my app.routing.ts I have added the MsalGuard on routes that require auth.

What I am seeing: those routes are redirecting to the login screen as expected, but when you authenticate, it asks to give permission to "myTrialApp" which is not the name of my app.

On a closer look at the MsalGuard in the debugger, I can see that the client Id it's using is undefined. I'm trying to understand what I need to change to make sure that the login page is using the correct client Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not working due to AoT. A nice workaround would be to be able to inject the MsalConfig, but that doesn't appear to be supported today in the library. For now I worked around this by defining my clientId in the environment.ts which is available at compile time.